Formula to Determine the Last Day of Work Period in Excel
I’m working on an Excel spreadsheet to manage my work and off days, but I'm stuck on creating a formula for column E. Here’s a brief overview of the table:

Column A: Date of the year
Column B: Code related to the work activity performed on that day
Column C: Number of days off resulting from the work activity in column B
Column D: Boolean value (False for workdays, True for days off)

Example of the results I’m trying to achieve in Column E. The dates in Column E should either repeat the date from Column A if it's a day off (Column D is True) or display the last day of the work period if it's a workday (Column D is False).
I need a formula for column E that should:

Repeat the date from column A if it's a day off (column D is True).
Otherwise, show the last day of the current work period.

I’ve tried several approaches but haven’t managed to get it right (I have tried to use the max, filter and xlookup formulas without success). Any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
Feel free to ask for any additional details if needed.
Thanks in advance!

Where is the "current work period", how have you written it?

The work period would be all the dates that has "False" in the Column D.

So you want a formula that says if COLUMN D = TRUE then 'give COLUMN A' else 'give Last day in column C that has a FALSE value next to it in Column D'?

This is one workaround. The formula is in M10 and drag down:
=IF(L10,I10,OFFSET(INDEX(I11:I$100,MATCH(TRUE,L11:L$100,0)),-1,0))
I used OFFSET to avoid the INDEX 0 input parameter.


If I understand it right you want this for row 5:
if(D5;A5;max(C$2:C5*not(D$2:D5)))
Edit the C5 and last D5 depending on if you want the last date of the full column or only the last date from that row and above.
